# Setting up fast_gettext search path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, gettext

I am trying to localize an existing Ruby on Rails project, and I have decided to use fast_gettext. I have tried to set things up as described on the github page (https://github.com/grosser/fast_gettext) and in this small tutorial (http://blog.lingohub.com/developers/2013/08/ruby-gettext-internationalization-tutorial-fest-gettext-gem/). However, when I do

```
rake gettext:find
```

it appears that only my .rb files are being searched and not my other files (importantly, the .erb files are not being checked).

In addition to updating my bundle to include the necessary gems, this is what I've done so far:

Added config/initializers/fast_gettext.rb. Here it is:

```
# config/initializers/fast_gettext.rb
FastGettext.add_text_domain 'app', :path => 'config/locales', :type => :yaml
FastGettext.default_available_locales = ['en','es']
FastGettext.default_text_domain = 'app'
```

I have also created lib/tasks/gettext.rake

```
namespace :gettext do
  def files_to_translate
    Dir.glob("{app,lib,config,locale}/**/*.{rb,erb,haml,slim,rhtml}")
  end
end
```

This is index.html.erb

```
<div class="home_title"><%= t(:xyz) %></div>
```

I am setting the locale in application_controller.rb, and if I manually modify the locale file (e.g. config/locales/es.yml), the text gets translated when I open the page. However, when I run gettext, it does not create an entry for this item. I end up with an empty app.pot:

```
# File headers....
# Copyright, my name, etc.
#
#, fuzzy
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: app 1.0.0\n"
"Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: \n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2014-03-19 16:52-0700\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: 2014-03-19 16:52-0700\n"
"Last-Translator: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>\n"
"Language-Team: LANGUAGE <LL@li.org>\n"
"Language: \n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=INTEGER; plural=EXPRESSION;\n"
```

As I said above, I believe that gettext is only checking .rb files (based on some hacked logs that I placed inside the gettext code). It could also be that I need to do something extra to configure gettext to recognize this is a string to be localized:

```
<%= t(:xyz) %>
```

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: BTW, I'm not married to fast_gettext. I will be happy with any tool that will parse my files and generate either .po or .yml locales.